# Build Fail : aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have a build step that is part of my deployment configuration. My coworker told me it had worked once in a blue moon

I kept on getting this error consistently when I ran this build step:

```
Deleting dirPath (qa.comedy.net\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319). [15:22:22]: 

[VSMSDeploy] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.\We
\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3588, 5): Web deployment task failed.((3/28/2012 3:22:22 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

Attempt to perform an unauthorized operation on file '4_0_30319'.
```

It seems that it is trying to delete the folder
aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319 , but has no permission to.

we run this build on a virtual machine.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue deploying as site with msdeploy and teamcity. I resolved it by deleteing these folders  from my website `aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319`

Comment: I had the exact same problem when using ftp publishing.  Just after the delete stage, the above folder structure was created on the remote server.  I have no idea why.  It has never done this before.  I simply deleted the above folder leaving root intact and then tried to publish again and it worked.

Comment: That works fine, but you'll have to keep doing that as automatic updates will repeatedly add the folder back in. See my answer for some permanent solutions.

Comment: Is this folder structure something Web Deploy drops if you do a "whatif" test execution?

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can delete this folder and the next deploy will work, but with the next windows update that runs the asp.net registration tool as part of it's install will add this folder back to all asp.net sites on IIS (with the incorrect permissions) - so your deployment will fail again. You can avoid this by

- Giving the deploy user elevated privileges ***(not a great solution for
  obvious reasons)***
- Add the folder structure to your SC so it gets
  deployed instead of the deployment trying to delete it ***(not ideal, but easiest)***
- Stop automatic windows updates ***(not sensible)***
- You might be able to do
  something like this
  http://blog.richardszalay.com/2012/12/18/demystifying-msdeploy-skip-rules/
  to ignore the folder in deployment ***(I've not tried this)***

Comment: I have run into this a couple times, and ended up doing your second suggestion: after deleting the folder manually, I add a `aspnet_client\system_web_4_0_30319\placeholder.txt` to SC so the folder gets created. I actually just linked to this article in the text file. Agree it's not ideal, but neither is some ASP tool that automatically runs and adds random files to a deployed application.

Comment: @gregmac Indeed I view the addition of this folder by the updates as a bug. It shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 4):

As [MemeDeveloper mentions in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22021704/173497), one way to fix this is to simply ignore that directory. Indeed, this is the easiest fix and doesn't require adding anything to your source control repository or build output. Just add the following to your *msdeploy.exe* command:

`-skip:Directory="aspnet_client"`

Comment: Hi! Where do you make this change?

Comment: @Patrick Wherever your deploy command is stored, e.g. a build app, a CI app; whatever is running the `msdeploy` command.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn’t using TeamCity but I *think* I also had *this* issue.  I was trying to deploy to Discount ASP.NET using VS2010 WebDeploy.  After reading what doglin and Dan posted, I found I could workaround this problem by checking the “Leave extra files on destination (do not delete)” box.  That may not be an option for everyone but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem during WebDeploy in TeamCity. I end up elevating privileges for WebDeploy account under which I do WebDeploy task. So the account have enough power to delete those folder (local admin role).